# Statement return invalid output

Tags: c#, operators, conditional-statements

See the below code

```
   totLen = (r.Field<int>("Quantity") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<int>("Quantity")) *
   ((r.Field<decimal>("Breath") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<decimal>("Breath")) * 
   (r.Field<decimal>("Length") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<decimal>("Length")) * 
   (r.Field<decimal>("Height") <= 0 ? r.Field<decimal>("Height") : r.Field<decimal>("Height")))
```

In this code I had think that if any value of the **r.Field(COLUMN NAME)** come zero than it should be replaced by 1 **only for multiplication** by using **? and :** *conditional* operator but its gives me wrong output and return a ZERO(0)... 
Can Any one suggest me why this happening?

Comment: Can you debug through check what is the values for each and what you are getting?

Comment: Nice Idea for dealing with zero

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? I don't understand why `totLen` should be non-zero if all fields are zero

Comment: its sure that there will be only one value will be zero....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "Height" field is `0` you're still using it in your multiplication.

Change

```
r.Field<decimal>("Height") <= 0 ? r.Field<decimal>("Height") : r.Field<decimal>("Height")
```

to

```
r.Field<decimal>("Height") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<decimal>("Height")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 totLen = (r.Field<int>("Quantity") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<int>("Quantity")) *
 ((r.Field<decimal>("Breath") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<decimal>("Breath")) * 
 (r.Field<decimal>("Length") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<decimal>("Length")) * 
 (r.Field<decimal>("Height") <= 0 ? 1 : r.Field<decimal>("Height")))
```

Try this